# New window opens when button is clicked but not when using .onclick()

Tags: javascript

I am using software that creates all the HTML/XML so I don't have this and I have created a button to open a form in a new window. When I physically click on this button, everything works. However when I run the code onload, I get a message saying that the page is blocked and I need to remove any popup blocker

```
    var button = getElement("GUID_of_Button"); 
    button.click();
```

This code works if I set to open the form in the same window as a tooltip but not as a new window. I tried on Chrome, Firefox and IE with same results. (no console error)

Not sure if this helps (get this when I inspect element)

```
<input name="buttoncontrol0F09F8F7" id="ID_buttoncontrol0F09F8F7" value="Click here" type="submit" title="Click here" class="Button_Standard" style="cursor: pointer;">==$0
```

Naturally I can remove any blockers but as this is for the whole office, I can't ask everyone to do this just so I can get this to work. Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of modern browsers that restricts the opening of new windows to user-initiated actions.
This is important as it mitigate security risks and gets rid of the most obnoxious advertising.
Unless you can get everyone to change their browser settings, you won't have a new window opened automatically.

Depending on the data you need to display, you could consider alternative to new windows such as modals / pop-ins. Take a look for example at [Bootstrap's modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 1):

Popup windows are generally used for advertisement and these windows will be opened without permission of user. Inorder to prevent this, most of the web browsers comes with popup blockers which should be explicitly configured by user if they want to automatically open something in a new window.

If you want to use this featue, you'll have to ask users to configure popup blockers in their web browser.